# Check if disk inserted into a preserved partition

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using `GetDriveTypeA("D:\\")` to check the existence of the "preserved D" drive, but it's always exist, even when a disk is not inserted into it. Why? It's even not visible in the Disk management when a disk is not inserted.

Comment: Call `GetDiskFreeSpace` and check the return value?

Comment: What is the return value you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a removable disk is not inserted does not mean the drive itself, or its assigned drive letter, does not exist. Windows system UIs may hide drives with ejected media (what management is the *user* going to perform on a drive without media?), but code can still interact with such drives if needed. That is why `GetDriveType()` does not fail if `D:` has been assigned to a drive.

If you really need to check if a disk is inserted, do something that requires a disk (like query the disk space, or the disk volume information), or drop to the MMC layer and use `DeviceIoControl()` to ask the drive directly if it has a disk inserted or not (and if needed, what type of disk).